# Words and expressions request for order

Tags: word-choice, expressions, phrase-requests, idioms

My mom bought home some fruit last week and before we are able to finish them all she got some more today so she told me, translated to English from my first language, that I should eat the fruit that is purchased earlier first, so I’m wondering what are the more idiomatic expressions that convey the same or the similar meaning of her words in English? I have in mind using ‘first bag’ and ‘second bag’ might work well like ‘eat the first bag of fruit before going on to the next’ could be understandable but I kind of doubt its idiomaticity.

As an expansion, what if the subject in question is something else,for instance, two bottles of cough drugs made on different dates, in which case the optimal order you take them depends on their respective expiration date instead of the time you bought them, should I say ‘take the bottle that expires sooner first’?

Comment: There are various ways you could say this - "Eat the oldest fruit first", "Eat last week's fruit first", for example.

Comment: This is a problem of inventory management. Since most products have a shelf life—they gradually rot, became less flavorable, or decay—the rule is “first in, first out.”

Comment: Thank you for the answer (-^O^-)

Comment: Thank you  for answering  (＾▽＾)

Comment: With packaged goods having 'best before' or 'expiry' dates, "Use up the shorter-dated crumpets first" is typical. But this only works for dated goods (unless one is being over-clever).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  shorter-dated, this is exactly the word I'm looking for, thanks a lot (●'◡'●)